# How can I extract human-readable text from a code snippet?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, text, rtf

I need to write a T-SQL query against a text column where some of the values are `html` or `asp.net` coding but include normal human-readable text. For example:

```
{\colortbl ;\red31\green73\blue125;\red0\green0\blue0;} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\lang1033\f0\fs22 All invoices to be emailed to Jack Jack.Marsman@brampton.ca
```

I don't need that information I need the real text; in this case I want to get just `All invoices to be emailed to Jack Jack.Marsman@brampton.ca`

Any suggestions on how to go about extracting the text without getting the coding?

Comment: What steps have you taken to solve this problem on your own?  Show us what you have done so far

Comment: What do you mean by "real text"? Can you show some sample data and the results you expect to get?

Comment: why do you still have text columns, they are deprecated.

Comment: @Pondlife {\colortbl ;\red31\green73\blue125;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\lang1033\f0\fs22 **All invoices to be emailed to Jack Jack.Marsman@brampton.ca** what's in bold is what I'm trying to get...all other is junk for these purposes.

Comment: @JasonCarter I did a basic select statement out of my customers table...

Comment: @HLGEM because it's not my program I'm just trying to pull some data from it.

Comment: do you have more examples? all the rows are like this one? It seems like a regex can do the trick but more meaningful examples would be great

Comment: That's not `HTML` or `asp.net` anything. That's RTF (Rich Text Formatting), and the values preceeded by `\` are RTF tags. (A search here can probably provide a regex or other code to extract text from RTF.) `RTF` is what's used to contain formatted text used by `WordPad` or the `RichEdit` control, and can be imported or exported from MS Word.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that there is no easy standard way to do this. I’d try creating a CLR since this kind of parsing is easier in C# or VB.NET.

You can also try using regex to strip out everything that’s not human readable.

Is all of your data in similar format like you already shown? If that’s the case then it comes down to calling substring several times…